# Has anyone ever really constructed a countable model of set theory that falls in the trap of the Skolem's Paradox?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

In an [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/#2) named 'Skolem’s Paradox' on SEP, there is a description of the Paradox I'm asking about here:

> Skolem's Paradox arises when we notice that the standard axioms of set theory can themselves be formulated as (countable) collection of first-order sentences. If these axioms have a model at all, therefore, then the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem ensures that they have a model with a countable domain. But this seems quite puzzling. How can the very axioms which prove Cantor's theorem on the existence of uncountable sets be satisfied by a model which is itself only countable? How can a countable model satisfy the first-order sentence which “says that” there are uncountably many things?

I wonder if anyone really has constructed a countable model of set theory that falls in the trap of the Skolem's Paradox. That is, they constructed a countable model of the usual first-order set theory, and proved that in that very model, there is an element $x$ such that the existence of an injective function from $x$ to *the set of natural numbers* $\Bbb{N}$ in the model can be denied in that theory (and hence, $x$ is uncountable).
Of course, how they verified that the $x$ above is really an uncountable 'set' seen from the theory/model may be done differently (, different from the way I describe above).

Some may suggest that one can use the method in the proof of the skolem theorem to generate such a model. But that method is not *really* *'constructive'* enough-- we don't know how the elements in the model behave. So, in the spirit of being *'constructive'*, such a model is more preferred:

1. its universe is computably enumerable (or at least decidable);
2. the relations (as sets) in this model are also computably enumerable (or at least decidable);
3. the collection of the relations in this model is also computably enumerable (or at least decidable).

If all 3 of the above conditions can't be met in one single model, then a model satisfying as many of them as possible is preferred.

Comment: The proof of the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem is fairly constructive. Are you familiar with it? If so, why does it not count as a "construction" in whatever sense you have in mind?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not very *constructive* though, it uses an infinite procedure  to get the closure of the skolem functions, which makes it hard for us to really grasp the behaviour of the elements in the universe of the countable model. A model who can be effectively manipulated (or can be dealt with using a computer program) is preferred.

Comment: Well there's a fundamental obstacle to that hope: [$\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or indeed much less) has no computable models](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc). This is basically a consequence of Tennenbaum's theorem - $\mathsf{PA}$ has no computable nonstandard models, and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ exists. *(I'm hiding some details here but the broad strokes are correct.)* But this has nothing to do with Lowenheim-Skolem, it's just something that happens with reasonably-powerful theories *(e.g. the theory $\mathsf{RCA_0}$)*.

Comment: Crossposted at [PSE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/93727/has-anyone-ever-really-constructed-a-countable-model-of-set-theory-that-falls-in) (FYI it's generally frowned upon to do that, especially without indicating the crosspost).

Comment: If you would like an even more explicit example than the Skolem hulls used in the proof of L-S, David Madore has [a nice list](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf) of large countable ordinals. Near the end, one of these ordinals $\alpha$ is such that the level $L_\alpha$ of constructible universe is a (countable) model of ZFC. This model contains an ordinal "$\omega_1^{L_\alpha}$", and $L_\alpha$ satisfies "there is no injection $\omega_1^{L_\alpha}\to\omega$"